# How to setup ethernet on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, ethernet

I just installed ubuntu server 16.04 lts to my local pc. I have a cable internet with no static ip. I am using a wireless router but first I am trying to get wired connection to start with. As I have no internet all my output here I have typed using my laptop so pls do consider any typo.

ifconfig -a

```
enp5s0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 94:de:80:c3:af:60
inet6 addr:fe80::96de:80ff:fec3:af60/64 Scope:link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric;1
RX packets:1 error:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 error:0 dropped:47 overruns:0 carrier:0
collision:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:215 (215.0 B) TX Bytes:0 (0.0B)

lo  Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBAK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric;1
RX packets:3481 error:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:3481 error:0 dropped:47 overruns:0 carrier:0
collision:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:258425 (258.4 kB) TX Bytes:258425 (258.4 kB)

wlp6s0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr c0:4a:00:2c:34:f2

BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:1 error:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 error:0 dropped:47 overruns:0 carrier:0
collision:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:215 (215.0 B) TX Bytes:0 (0.0B)
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network 
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co.,Ltd
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
logical name: enp5s0
version: 06
serial: 94:de:80:c3:af:60
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 
10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 
driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 
link=YES 
multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
resources: irq:31 memory: d00004000-d0004fff memory:40000000-d0003ffff 
ioport:b000(size=256)

+-network DISABLED
description:Wireless interface
.....
```

sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp5s0
#iface enp5s0 inet dhcp
iface enp5s0 inet static
address 192.168.0.107
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
```

Here are host details:
/etc/hostname

```
kronos
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 kronos
```

Here is the router details:

```
Wirelesss:
DESKTOP-LDN5UMS                192.168.0.100
android-9b185c2fe6197052       192.168.0.106

Wired:
nothing there even though ubuntu server is connected
LAN
Mac address:XXXXXXXXX
ip address: 192.168.0.1
subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
DHCP:on
```

sudo ifdown enp5s0

```
ifdown: interface enp5s0 not configured
```

Still no internet

Comment: Please clarify. Is the router you are connected to 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.56.1? Your results above are confusing.

Comment: can you please check now? I edited my post cause it was hard to read

Comment: Ahh! If your router is 192.168.0.1, I shall edit my answer to conform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem after 8 hrs struggle. I know some one like me can face the same issue later. That's I am giving my solution. Everything was good in my setting but still I was not getting any internet. So I thought may be it is my Gigabyte 990 FX UD3 motherboard. So I found inside the bios of MOBO, there is a feature called IOMMU, just turn it enable then save the settings of the mobo. Start the server..Done. Internet is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you amend your `interfaces` file to include DNS nameservers and to clean it up a bit:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp5s0
#iface enp5s0 inet dhcp

iface enp5s0 inet static
      address 192.168.0.130
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.0.1
      dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
```

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown enp5s0 && sudo ifup -v enp5s0
```

Did you get the requested address?

```
ifconfig enp5s0
```

Are you connected?

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Please read the post again I simplified it and it is now easy to read

Comment: thanks for your reply. I really don't understand why it is not working.Here
is the snap shop now:
[link]https://imgur.com/a/Y3Fui

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Stopping and restarting networking is deprecated. Please do not do so! Please reboot and show us: `ip addr show` and also: `ping -c3 192.168.0.1` Finally, are you sure that the address you used, 192.168.0.108, is outside the DHCP pool in the router?

Comment: ok I logged in to my router and found the range :192.168.0.100-199
[link]https://imgur.com/toXyBys

Comment: I suggest that you change the `interfaces ` file to specify an address *outside* that range; 192.168.0.50, for instance. Reboot.